# Windows 10 localhost request ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, windows, localhost

#### Problem:

I am running a PHP script (using Lumen framework) on Windows 10, listening for request on `localhost:8090`.

- When I send a `GET` request using Postman, it returns the response I desire.
- When I send a request using `curl` from the terminal, I receive the desired response.
- But when I send a request from my Javascript code (using Fetch or Axios), I receive the error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8090`.

#### What I've already done:

I already tried to disable the Windows Firewall and the windows 10 Defender, but it didn't solve the issue. I tried to do all these things on a newly installed Windows 10, the result was the same.

I tried to allow the port on the Firewall, still didn't help.

I tried using Node-Fetch and Axios as well, it didn't help.

#### Codes:

Javascript code:

```
const axios = require("axios")

console.log("Sending the request...")

axios({
    url: 'http://localhost:8090',
})
.then(res => {
    console.log("res arrived")
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log("err happened", { err })
})

console.log("Request sent")
```

PHP terminal command for running the Lumen app:

```sh
php -S localhost:8090 -t public
```

#### Summary

So the Lumen app is running since I can get the response using Postman and Curl. It is only not working using Javascript.

Comment: Directly enter http://localhost:8090 to URL bar in the browser and check if it working.

Comment: any error logs etc available on the server side perhaps?

Comment: How about trying another port? Your 8090 could have something else running on it. You can also consider killing the port first then restart your server

Comment: I tried entering directly into the browser, of course it is working.
I am psting the more detailed error in my next comment.
The port is not in use, I tried many different ports but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why this fixes the error, but try having your PHP script listen on 127.0.0.1 explicitly instead of localhost. This fixed the problem you were having above. My suspicion is that the term "localhost" was being interpreted differently by PHP (and Postman, curl, the browser, etc.) and by the JS client. But by explicitly specifying 127.0.0.1 there is no ambiguity.

```
$ php -S 127.0.0.1:8090
```